# Can there be multiple private keys for a given public key in attribute-based encryption

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption

I know for “normal” public key algorithms like RSA, there is only a single private key for a given public key, but I’m not clear on whether ABE uses a different kind of algorithm where that is no longer true.